# Why do you chose to not use Microsoft Access to develop applications?

Tags: security, microsoft-access, vba, office365, microsoft-office

Over the years I have heard from many Corporate IT departments and application developers as to why they chose to not use MS-Access, and even not allow it to be used, for developing applications. The primary pain point is it's not secure. I recently discovered that macros, queries and tables can be exported from an external Access database to encrypted and compiled Access databases. Can you please share your thoughts about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

My organization’s experience has been that when we upgrade from one version of Access to the next - and on at least one occasion, when we applied a patch to Access - the saved code in the Access files stops working, and we have to “recompile” the code. When the default format for Access databases went from .MDB to .AccDB, there were also enough language changes that we had to do some significant rewrites. At that point, the head of IT pushed through a migration of most data to an enterprise web-based application with SQLServer as the backend, and basically de-certified organizational support for most Access applications. If an office builds a local solution for something where the data involved is not in the organizational central app/db, they’re on their own; organizational IT will only support issues clearly related to computer or installation problems, not Access code or data.